# How to use multiple slideshowGroups and the same config object

Tags: highslide

I want to use **the same config object** for two or more galleries on one page - one gallery per article, that is  generated by my CMS.
At the same time **different slideshowGroup options** should be added inline(!) to the thumbnails of these galleries, since I've to use the individual article numbers (e.g. art473) as slideshouGrroup options.

Is there any chance to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use this scenario:

1) create common file with configuration, includes in header.
2) on the subpage in  tags place a slideshowGroup.

Result:

```
    <head>
    <script src="common.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <h2>Your article subpage</h2>
    <script>
    slideshowGroup = '/';

    </script>

<!-- your gallery in HTML -->

    </body>
```

Comment: If I understand you right, I'd put all site-specific configuration settings for Highslide JS in my /js/highslide/highslide.config.js and then add the article-specific settings - here the slideshowGroups - dynamically by creating inline Javascripts, for example looking like this:

`<script>
var config_art473= {
 slideshowGroup: 'art473',
 transitions: ['expand', 'crossfade']
 };
</script>`